# Issues with button widgets and virtual android devices on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am new to flutter and I was trying to tie a function to button widgets on flutter. It did not work and I honestly do not know why. I put my code in the picture and I would also copy and paste the code below.

```
//ignore_for_file: deprecated_member_use

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(FirstApp());

class FirstApp extends StatelessWidget {
  void answerQuestion(){
    print ('Question answered!');
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text('The question!'),
            RaisedButton(child: Text('Answer 1'), onPressed: answerQuestion,),
            RaisedButton(child: Text('Answer 2'), onPressed: answerQuestion,),
            RaisedButton(child: Text('Answer 3'), onPressed: answerQuestion,)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what was the problem in your code? its work correctly and print the message `Question answered!` when button is pressed

Comment: i have seen what the problem is. Thanks a lot!